# Grafana dashboard graphs does not shows units

Tags: sql-server, grafana, influxdb, telegraf, grafana-dashboard

I am new in grafana-influxdb-telegraf platforms.
My environment is, i have influxdb and grafana which runs on linux 7.
Also i have sql servers which runs on Windows. And thatswhy i have configured telegraf for capture logs.
When i import some dashboard to grafana looks everything ok and graphs are works. But my question is for example, graph should be looks like below.
[image]

But my graph not show units and not colorful.

[image]

Can somebody please help me to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the first image, Grafana is configured (Preferences) to use the "Light" UI Theme.
2. You can make them more colorful, by increasing the "Area fill" parameter in Graph > Panel > Display, configuration.
3. The "Memory Manager" and "Lock Requests" panels are showing units (B), I think it's not expected to show any unit in the others panels.